# Latin1_General_100_CI_AS Collation on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, collation

We currently have a SQL 2005 Server which we use as a report server.

This now needs to link to a Navision database on a SQL 2014 server using collation Latin1_General_100_CI_AS.

I have happily set up a  linked server on SQL 2005 but any queries using it fail.

Can anyone advise on how to add Latin1_General_100_CI_AS collation on SQL Server 2005?

Is this even possible or will have to upgrade the SQL Server?

Kind regards

Rob

Comment: This question would be best for Super User or another community.

Comment: I think you probably just want something like `...join linkserver.db.dbo.table  as table2 on table2.column collate SQL_Latin1_General_100_CI_AS table1.otherColumn...`

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that SQL 2005 seems to not support Latin1_General_100_CI_AS out of the box so doing something like you suggest is not currently possible.

Comment: In fact simply doing a select * from a table in the linked database gives the following error. 

Msg 4012, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An invalid tabular data stream (TDS) collation was encountered.